# Strdup free still result in memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, strdup

I am still not able to get my head around why there is still memory leak here because of `strdup` (that's what the error says), I made sure I freed all the allocated memory of `strdup` before removing the node and I freed all the nodes at the end of the program.
What did I miss?

Here is the code I wrote:

```c
struct background_processes *head = NULL;

struct background_processes {
    int pid;
    char *cmd_name;
    struct background_processes *next;
};

// Add a background process to the Background processes LinkedList
void add_background_process(int pid, char *name) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct background_processes));
        if (head == NULL) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        head->pid = pid;
        head->cmd_name = strdup(name);
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        struct background_processes *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct background_processes));
        if (current->next == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        current->next->pid = pid;
        current->next->cmd_name = strdup(name);
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}

// Remove a background process from the Background processes LinkedList
void remove_background_process(int pid) {
    struct background_processes *current = head;
    struct background_processes *prev = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        /* If the process is running */
        if (pid == current->pid) {
            if (current == head) {
                head = head->next;
                free(current->cmd_name);
                free(current);
                current = head;
            } else {
                prev->next = current->next;
                free(current->cmd_name);
                free(current);
                current = prev->next;
            }
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

void free_linkedlist() {
    struct background_processes *current = head;
    struct background_processes *after;

    while (current != NULL) {
        after = current->next;
        free(current->cmd_name);
        free(current);
        current = after;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Some code 

    while (1) {
        // Some other code
        
        execute_pipeline(l);
    }
    // Freeing all allocated memory
    free_linkedlist();
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: which tool is reporting the memory leak?

Comment: We cannot possibly test your code, it does not compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If the problem can't be found in the code you posted, it's most probably in `execute_pipeline` or in the allocation of `l`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's raising a compile error : ```error: leak of ‘strdup(name)’ [CWE-401] [-Werror=analyzer-malloc-leak]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no visible leak in the posted code. The problem must be somewhere else:

- the list might be corrupted during the execution of unpublished code.
- unpublished code might allocate memory with `strdup()` and leak it.
- some of the nodes might get modified, overwriting `cmd_name` fields.
- some other undefined behavior might have this side effect.

It is recommended to avoid duplicating the allocation and deallocation code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct background_processes {
    int pid;
    char *cmd_name;
    struct background_processes *next;
};

struct background_processes *head = NULL;

// Add a background process to the Background processes LinkedList
void add_background_process(int pid, const char *name) {
    // Allocate and initialize a new node
    struct background_processes *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->pid = pid;
    node->cmd_name = strdup(name);
    node->next = NULL;

    // Append the new node to the list
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        struct background_processes *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = node;
    }
}

// Remove a background process from the Background processes LinkedList
void remove_background_process(int pid) {
    struct background_processes *current = head;
    struct background_processes *prev = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        struct background_processes *next = current->next;
        // If the process is running
        if (pid == current->pid) {
            // detach the node
            if (current == head) {
                head = next;
            } else {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            // deallocate the node
            free(current->cmd_name);
            free(current);
            current = next;
        } else {
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }
}

void free_linkedlist(void) {
    struct background_processes *current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        struct background_processes *next = current->next;
        free(current->cmd_name);
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}
```